# Flowtype: string type is incompatible with string enum

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Why does flow not allow this:

```
/* @flow */

const f1 = (p1: {[string]: string}) =>  undefined;
const f2 = (p2: {status: 'ok' | 'not_ok' }) =>  f1(p2);
```

[Flowtype repl](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBjOA7AzgFzCgEYwBeMACgAdiAuMAbwG0CAnAS2wHMBdB9l24BfAJTkAfGDABXbABMAplC6L5Abkw4CRAEzkq1XQ0YEAhvhm4GAcjgBrG2AA+YG9jj4A+g6djJ0iQ0uqLqQA)

Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that `f1` potentially mutate the `status` prop. Hence immutability was needed.

[solution](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBjOA7AzgFzCgEYwBeMACgAdiAuMAbwGoBtAgJwEtsBzAXQacevAL4BKcgD4wYAK7YAJgFMoPZYoDcmHASIAmclWr6GjAgEN8c3AwDkcANZ2wAHzB3scfAH0nLiWlZEhp9cU0gA)

```
/* @flow */

const f1 = (p1: {+[string]: string}) =>  undefined;
const f2 = (p2: {status: 'ok' | 'not_ok' }) =>  f1(p2);
```